# How to show a progress bar while tar a folder recursively?

Tags: shell-script, tar

In bash-script execution of taring not shown a progress bar, how to show a progress bar while taring a directory?

Comment: duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/168749/is-there-a-way-to-see-any-tar-progress-per-file

Answer (score 5):

You can use [pv](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pv).
For more details see Superuser Q/A [Is there a way to see any tar progress per file?](https://superuser.com/questions/168749/is-there-a-way-to-see-any-tar-progress-per-file)